# Including a notebook in another notebook in IPython?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have a notebook which I intend to use as a library for other notebooks.
It has some functions that can ready certain types of files etc.

How can I include that notebook in a new notebook that should be able to use the functions in the library notebook?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20186344/478206, https://stackoverflow.com/q/19082397/478206 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/19564625/478206 are all asking the same question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

googling for `notebook import hook` yield some [example](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/6011986)s. This is still experimental, but you are welcomed to improved it. I would suggest also using the `--script` flag that save an importable `.py` file every time you save the notebook.

Comment: That script flag is very handy. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, how to use the --script flag?

Answer (score 7):

You can just enter `%run 'NotebookA.ipynb'` in Notebook B and you should be good to go!

Comment: Just curious. Is it possible to include a relative path to the other runbook? If not, how about a full path? For some reason, %run is appending .py to the end of my filename.

Answer (score 2):

With `import_ipynb` library using `A.ipynb` from `B.ipynb` is as simple as writing

```
import import_ipynb
import A
```

in `B.ipynb`.

Actually this library is just one file I've taken from the official [jupyter howto](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jupyter/notebook/blob/master/docs/source/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.ipynb) and wrapped into a package installable via

```
pip install import-ipynb
```

It's also possible to write `from A import foo`, `from A import *` and so on.