# How can I import from another ipython-notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython

I'd like to import a func from another ipython-notebook. Say,

`common_func.ipynb` has `def func_a()`

When I create a new notebook, how can I access the `func_a` which is from another notebook but in the same folder and same ipython instance?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20186344/478206, https://stackoverflow.com/q/19082397/478206 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/19564625/478206 are all asking the same question.

Comment: Please also see this 2019 follow-up on how to selectively import from another notebook: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54317381

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the IPython mailing list this was discussed very recently, see [here](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/ipython-dev/2013-October/012528.html). Finally ([here](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/ipython-dev/2013-October/012538.html)), an example notebook was found, which shows a way to import code from other notebooks. This notebook can be found in the `examples/notebooks` directory, and looks like [this](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/master/examples/IPython%20Kernel/Importing%20Notebooks.ipynb). You 'just' have to define the *NotebookLoader* and *NotebookFinder* classes as shown in the notebook. I've tried with IPython 1.1.0 and it works fine!

Comment: Specifically, the link is currently [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/master/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.ipynb).

Comment: or [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/master/examples/IPython%20Kernel/Importing%20Notebooks.ipynb)

Comment: Gist with that code: https://gist.github.com/alexoliveira/ae5c896d3b065ecccdb170f5609673a4. To use it, put `notebook_importer.py` in your iPython root. Import it using `from notebook_importer import *`. Finally import your notebook! (ex: my_notebook.ipynb with `import my_notebook`). Now all your functions/classes in that notebook file are accessible.

Comment: An alternative method is to use the %run magic function (from https://blog.sicara.com/present-data-science-results-jupyter-notebook-import-into-another-108433bc8505)

Answer (score 29):

There is now a dedicated function to achieve this called [`nbimporter`](https://github.com/grst/nbimporter) - installed via pip.

Usage:

```
import nbimporter
import notebookName as name
name.functionName()
```

And if you update *notebookName*.ipynb then reload by:

```
reload(name)
```

or this for Python 3 (*reload not included by default*):

```
from importlib import reload
reload(name)
```

Comment: does this still work? I'm having the below error the second time I reload:
reload(): module <module name> not in sys.modules

Comment: I agree there is something odd with `reload()` - on second run it spits out _not in sys.modules_ error.
Solved for me by adding the `import notebookName as name` with `reload(notebookName)` and running twice.

Comment: And where does reload() come from?

Comment: This overflow has some information about reload, which is a default part of python 2.x: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module

Answer (score 28):

When you start ipython use the --script flag: For example

```
ipython notebook --script
```

Then whenever you save your notebook "common_func.ipnb" it will also create a file entitled "common_func.py."  You can import functions from that by using

```
from common_func import func_a
```

If you change the common_func notebook, you may need to use

```
reload()
```

Comment: This flag is not available on the stable version of ipython 1.10.

Comment: I like this solution despite the overhead of extra .py and .pyc files strewn about because it's so easy to implement and doesn't require the extra code from @Jakob's suggestion.

Comment: As of ipython 3.0, the `--script` flag is deprecated. `jupyter nbconvert --to script [notebook]` appears to be the replacement (in 4.1.0).

Comment: Where to use `reload()`? It's error: NameError: name 'reload' is not defined

Answer (score 13):

Another option is [`ipynb`](https://github.com/ipython/ipynb). A nice benefit over `nbimporter` is that it can import just the definitions, while not executing the rest of the code. It's fairly new at this point (0.5).

```
pip install ipynb
```

And then:

```
import ipynb.fs.defs.my_other_notebook as other
```

Comment: However, this may not work if the notebook contains ipython magics: https://ipynb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: doesn't work in colab

ImportError: Could not import ....  for ipynb.fs.full.polygon: incorrect version or language

Answer (score 2):

[importnb](https://github.com/deathbeds/importnb) is an option. It has some nice features like fuzzy matching to help you find your notebook and aiding in importing notebooks where the name would normally be an issue.

#### Example adapted from OP

Imagine you have a notebook named `common_func.ipynb` with the following function saved in it:

```py
def func_a(x):
    return x + 67
```

Then you are working in a new notebook, `Untitled1.ipynb`.

To use `func_a` in the current notebook `Untitled1.ipynb`, in a cell run `%pip install importnb`. That will install the `importnb package` in the current environment backing the current notebook. (It won't do anything if you already have `importnb` installed.) You are welcome to install the package your favorite way as well.

Put `common_func.ipynb` or a copy of it in the current working directory where you are saving the current notebook `Untitled1.ipynb`.

Then in the current notebook you can use `importnb` to import the notebook `common_func.ipynb` and use `func_a` from it, like so:

```py
from importnb import Notebook
with Notebook(): 
    import common_func
common_func.func_a(2)
```