# How to include iPython notebook

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I would like to import functions from one iPython's notebook into another iPython's notebook. Is it possible? If so how to achieve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I import from another ipython-notebook?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564625/how-can-i-import-from-another-ipython-notebook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: [import iPython functions](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/2.x/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.ipynb).
Helped me as well.