# load notebook as module in ipython

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, python-import

I want to load the content of a `notebook` as a module in `ipython` like we do in normal cases. We add a file with the name `__init__.py` in the directory of the module of interest and that enable us to load it from another python file by doing `from fileName import *`. Now I can't get it work with ipython. Can anyone help me to figure this out ?

Many thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I import from another ipython-notebook?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564625/how-can-i-import-from-another-ipython-notebook)

Answer (score 1):

The notebook format is not Python code. You can convert it using [nbconvert](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/notebook/nbconvert.html), e.g.:

```
ipython nbconvert --to python notebook.ipynb
```

Comment: I don't want to convert it to python. I wanted simply to add a `notebook` as a module in another `ipython` file.

Comment: If you want to import it, It has to be a Python module, `.py` or the like.