# Issues importing a function from another python file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am a novice programmer and have ran into an issue trying to import a function I have written into another file. I think my issue probably has something to do with how my directory is set up. I run python in a jupyter notebook, and my directory looks something like this now:

```py
-Desktop
   |
   -pythonCode
        |
        -leisure
            |
            -quadratics
                 |
                 -quadEquatSolver.ipynb
                 -_init_.ipynb
                 -problems.ipynb
```

I want to import the function quadSolver() from quadEquatSolver.ipynb into my problems.ipynb file. I have read a few solutions on this forum, but what I found either did not work for me, or was over my head.

I have tried

```py
from quadEquatSolver import quadSolver
```

But I get an error message that states the module is not found.

I also have tried

```py
from . quadEquatSolver import quadSolver
```

and

```py
from .quadEquatSolver import quadSolver
```

But this gives me the same issue.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ipynb import another ipynb file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186344/ipynb-import-another-ipynb-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I import from another ipython-notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564625/how-can-i-import-from-another-ipython-notebook)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the first sentence in this [link](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.html), you would realize that import simply doesn't assist in loading the file because you are dealing with python notebooks and not python files. Try using the steps given [here](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.html)

There is another way of using ipynb, so first install ipynb from your command prompt using following command: pip install import-ipynb

```
import import_ipynb
import quadEquatSolver
```

Comment: You are great, thanks so much! I need to learn more about the differences between python and ipython. I did not even realize it was a different thing until your post.

Comment: I am glad this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried eliminating the spacebetween the . and quadEquatSolver.

So

```
from .quadEquatSolver import quadSolver
```