# Unable to import python file

Tags: python, import, module

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PluPH.png)

Whats the issue here? refer to image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMbxS.png)s

Comment: OTM is not a python file, is a jupyter notebook file. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186344/importing-an-ipynb-file-from-another-ipynb-file)  SO question on how to import ipynb files

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to import Jupyter Notebook as python module instead of regular py file. You can hook the Jupyter Notebook though as shown here:
[Importing Jupyter Notebooks as Modules](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.html).

Comment: There's a couple packages to make this easier. In particular, see about importnb [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/package-for-importing-jupyter-notebooks-as-modules/12923/2?u=fomightez) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58086016/8508004).