# Import other class does not work in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I have a file named **rentalcar.ipynb** with class inside named **rentalcar**
I am trying to import this class using other file **customer.ipynb**,

I am still getting this error

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 2
      1 from datetime import datetime
----> 2 from rentalcar import rentalcar
      4 class Customer:
      5         def __init__(self, name, rental_company):

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rentalcar'
```

Any Idea how to fix this, or should I run this from Python shell as ".py" extension to run correctly?

Comment: You have not shown the actual error message.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot import a class from one Jupyter Notebook into another Jupyter Notebook because Jupyter Notebooks are not designed to be imported.

You can still work in multiple notebooks but after you confirm your class works transfer it to a python file and import it with a from {file_name} import {function or class}

Comment: Not natively, but you can use notebook `.ipynb` files for import by installing additional libraries. See [my comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77981751/import-other-class-does-not-work-in-jupyter-notebook/77981913#comment137479107_77981913). I tend to like using [`importnb`](https://github.com/deathbeds/importnb#importnb-imports-notebooks-as-python-modules) for this. There's no need to convert to a `.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter notebooks by themselves are not designed to be used as libraries - importing a notebook into another notebook or into a python module cannot work because the python-interpreter does not understand the `.ipynb`-format. A python-interpreter wants to import python-modules, it needs `.py`-files (containing python source-code as plaintext, no concepts like a jupyter-notebook-"cell").

You have two options:

(1) use a third-party tool to turn notebooks into python-modules. I have used [fastai-nbdev](https://nbdev1.fast.ai/export.html), a wide-scoped tool for making notebooks, not modules, the building blocks for python applications. It not only adresses importing, but also documentation and testing. An interesting approach, but I don't think it ever really took off anywhere. Google also shows me [exporter](https://pypi.org/project/exporter/), but it seems like a very small project.

(2) put the code that you need in both notebooks into your own custom `.py`-library and import that into both. Use `.ipynb` for plotting/analysis/exploration and use `.py`-files for code like your rentalcar-class. Most functions and (imo) all classes should be defined there.

I recommend (2). The point of notebooks is that you can easily change and reload/recalculate stuff while keeping your variables in the interpreter. When you have code that behaves like a library, you are not getting the benefits of notebooks for that code but you are missing out on all the tooling that works well for `.py` but not for `.ipynb`. A non-exhaustive list of things that work better for `.py` than for `.ipynb`: unit-testing, version control, type-checking, autocomplete, all things IDE, code reuse.

So everytime you have some semi-complex code in your notebook and it becomes stable enough that you don't need to reload it all the time, put it in your `.py`-file. A single such file should be enough in the beginning, but you can split it further if you feel like you need to.

Comment: There's no need to turn the notebook into a module. You can import it via `importnb`, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/package-for-importing-jupyter-notebooks-as-modules/12923/2?u=fomightez) and [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/best-practices-re-reusable-code/22194/2?u=fomightez) and [example spelled out more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58086016/8508004). I would think this at least is in the vein of option (1)?

Comment: @Wayne that is also interesting and I didn't know it. nbdev tries to let you develop normal modules with jupyter-notebook, importnb extends pythons import-mechanism so that ipynb can be imported. Not sure if either is really a good idea, I always go the route of refactoring my code out from the notebook into a normal `.py`-file.

Comment: I agree the speed of pure python makes it a convenient choice when you have to scale. However, it is good to have these other tools handy at times.

Comment: @Wayne the speed of python-code from .ipynb and .py files should be exactly the same, no? Because jupyter-lab/notebook uses Ipython, which uses a normal python-interpreter, probably Cpython.

Comment: It depends on how you call things. I see a huge speed increase when I call a pure Python script in a notebooks using `%run -i myscript.py` vs IPython-based script that has magics and other Ipython/Jupyter conveniences that I call with `%run -i my_developmental_IPython_script.ipy`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
%run rentalcar
```

then use your function:

```
rentalcar([params])
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this example use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58086016/8508004) of [importnb](https://github.com/deathbeds/importnb#importnb-imports-notebooks-as-python-modules):

For sake of my test, I made a class named `RentalCar` in `rentalcar.ipynb`.

Install [importnb](https://github.com/deathbeds/importnb#importnb-imports-notebooks-as-python-modules). The three options are listed under 'installing importnb'(https://github.com/deathbeds/importnb#installing-importnb). Use the conda or mamba option if you use Anaconda/conda, otherwise use `pip`.

Then in the notebook where I wanted to import, I ran this as a cell:

```py
from importnb import imports
with imports("ipynb"):
    import rentalcar
```

OP can put that into `customer.ipynb`.

Now in the next cell, I can define a instance of `RentalCar()` this way:

```py
rc = rentalcar.RentalCar()
```

Because OP didn't [use CamelCase/ CapWords convention for the class name](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#class-names), **that line equivalent for OP in `customer.ipynb` would be**:

```py
rc = rentalcar.rentalcar()
```

Enjoy using your class instance.