# Importing jupyter notebook in another notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, jupyter-notebook

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186344/ipynb-import-another-ipynb-file) answer I encounter the following error msg, after running the script:

```
import my_jupyter_notebook

importing Jupyter notebook from my_jupyter_notebook.ipynb
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-10-c029d443b8ae> in <module>()
     89 sys.meta_path.append(NotebookFinder())
     90 
---> 91 import my_jupyter_notebook

C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in 
_find_and_load(name, import_)

C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in 
_find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in 
_load_unlocked(spec)

C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in 
_load_backward_compatible(spec)

<ipython-input-7-e4645f3088dd> in load_module(self, fullname)
     38         # load the notebook object
     39         with io.open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
---> 40             nb = current.read(f, 'json')
     41 
     42 

NameError: name 'current' is not defined
```

How can I solve this?