# import a function from another .ipynb file

Tags: python, import, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I defined a hello world function in a file called 'functions.ipynb'. Now, I would like to import functions in another file by using "import functions". I am sure that they are in the same folder. However, it still shows that "ImportError: No module named functions". By the way, I am using jupyter notebook. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ipynb import another ipynb file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186344/ipynb-import-another-ipynb-file)

Answer (score 102):

You'll want to use the [ipynb package/module importer](https://github.com/ipython/ipynb). You'll need to install it: `pip install ipynb`.

Create a Notebook named `my_functions.ipynb`. Add a simple function to it.

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)
```

Then, create a second IPython Notebook and import this function with:

```
from ipynb.fs.full.my_functions import factorial
```

Then you can use it as if it was in the same IPython Notebook:

```
testing = factorial(5)
```

See the [documentation](https://ipynb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for more details.

Comment: This does not work for me I always get this error  KeyError: '__package__'. The environment I use for notebooks is Azure Databricks and python 3. Is there a solution to fix this?

Comment: Make sure you install the package ipynb otherwise it will not work!

Comment: What if `my_functions` contains some code that I don't want to execute, but only want a function from the file?

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ipynb.fs.full.my_functions' I am getting this error,Can someone advice the cause for that,,I installed ipynb as well,,,

Comment: @suresh_chinthy Make sure that all the notebooks are in the same directory.

Comment: @Milos then use `import ipynb.fs.defs.my_functions` as documented here https://github.com/ipython/ipynb

Comment: @racoon_lord I am using the same syntax to import only function definitions. While this is working in .ipynb files. For some reasons I have to convert my second python notebook file to .py format. But this time, it is executing code of first Notebook as whole (including the code that I do not want to execute) instead of only function I want to call.  Any solution to this?

Comment: Actually I am performing Machine learning in first file and from second file I am executing function to check predictions. (Do no want to run training part again).

Answer (score 9):

For my use case the ipnyb import didn't work for some reason. I had to use Jupyter Notebook magic cell to import my function.:

```
%run MyOtherNotebook.ipynb     #this is were my function was stored
function(df)                    #then simply run the function
```

Answer (score 7):

You can save functions.ipynb as functions.py and can import the file as `import functions`. Now you can use any function defined in the functions file as `functions.function_name`
For eg, if add is a function,

```
functions.add(5,3)
```

after importing will work.

Answer (score 4):

@David Rinck's answer solved the problem, but I'd like to recommend you add the boilerplate `__name__ == "__main__"` to guard the scripts you don't want to accidentally invoke. It works the [same way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/419185/3552975) as in a usual Python file.

If a .ipynb file a.ipynb is imported by another one b.ipynb

```
from ipynb.fs.full.a import factorial
```

the `__name__` in a.ipynb would be `ipynb.fs.full.a` rather than `"__main__"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the solution provided by @David Rinck but beware that the ipynb file that you are importing the function from will run as a whole. So it is advisable that the file does not have any code the runs and only has functions that you may need.
I tried it myself and the same thing happened to me.
An easy solution that I resort to is just make a .py file containing the functions that I need and just import the functions from that file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33937256)