# Google Colab - Call function from another .ipynb file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have a local (not in Colab) Jupyter notebook that calls a function from another Jupyter notebook, it works fine. I've used David Rinck's answer from here: [import a function from another .ipynb file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44116194/import-a-function-from-another-ipynb-file) and used this line to import the function:
`from ipynb.fs.full.MyFunctions import MyFunction`

I've imported these two notebooks into Colab and when I run the main notebook I get the following error:
`No module named 'ipynb.fs.full.MyFunctions'`

What have I missed in the process of importing to Colab?
 (I've run `!pip install ipynb` in Colab as well)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `import-ipynb` package.

Starting by installing:

```
!pip install import_ipynb
import import_ipynb
```

Then,

```
 import "your .ipynb file"
```

For Example, I have a `sqroot.ipynb` file with a function

```
def sqroot(x):
  return x**.5
```

We can run this function using the following:

```
import sqroot
sqroot.sqroot(2)
```