# How can I run another ipynb file from ipynb file?

Tags: python, jupyter, autorun

I want to run another b.ipynb file from the a.ipynb file.

When I run a specific code in a.ipynb and run the b.ipynb file, the results are saved in the script when I run b.ipynb in Jupyer Notebook.

for example :

a.ipynb

```
run b.ipynb ..?
```

b.ipybn

```
print("5")
```

Then run the a.ipynb script and open b.ipynb.

I want to see in
b.ipynb

```
print("5")
>> 5
```

What code should I write in the a.ipynb file?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the magic function `%run`

Usage:

```
%run [-n -i -e -G]
     [( -t [-N<N>] | -d [-b<N>] | -p [profile options] )]
     ( -m mod | file ) [args]
```

Parameters after the filename are passed as command-line arguments to the program (put in sys.argv). Then, control returns to IPython’s prompt.

This is similar to running at a system prompt python file args, but with the advantage of giving you IPython’s tracebacks, and of loading all variables into your interactive namespace for further use (unless -p is used).

The file is executed in a namespace initially consisting only of **name**=='**main**' and sys.argv constructed as indicated. It thus sees its environment as if it were being run as a stand-alone program (except for sharing global objects such as previously imported modules). But after execution, the IPython interactive namespace gets updated with all variables defined in the program (except for **name** and sys.argv).

Comment: Oh, as you say, I could use "name == 'main' and sys.argv" to achieve the desired result.
One problem, however, is that if I place run inside a function, it won't work.                    
"run auto-run.ipynb"
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

example of this will be something like
[import a function from another .ipynb file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44116194/import-a-function-from-another-ipynb-file)

You have to `pip install ipynb` first

> first.ipynb

```
def print():
   print('Stack Overflow')
```

> second.ipynb

```
from ipynb.fs.full.first import print
print()
```