# Importing function from existing Jupyter notebook to a new notebook

Tags: python, function, import, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to import a function from an existing Jupyter notebook to a new notebook. Both the notebooks are saved in a virtual environment that I have been working on. The command that I am trying to execute in the **new notebook** is as follows:

```
from Probability.ipynb import norm_cdf
```

Probability = old notebook

norm_cdf = function name

I am getting the error below:

---

```
ModuleNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-4-9659a841148e> in <module>
----> 1 from Probability.ipynb import norm_cdf

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Probability'
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [import a function from another .ipynb file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44116194/import-a-function-from-another-ipynb-file)

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly you should use the tools provided by [ipynb package/module importer](https://github.com/ipython/ipynb). You can then import the function like this.

```
from ipynb.fs.full.Probability import norm_cdf
```

Hope this helps, best wishes.