# import files from different directory in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, ipython, workflow

Importing functions from an external ipynb file works as intended if it is in the same directory. However, if I have a project with multiple directories, I would like to be able to import functions from other directories. I understand that it may be easier to use another IDE for this purpose, however, I am documenting my work and would like to continue leveraging Jupyter Notebook's seamless Markdown integration.

I am not seeing anything in the `ipynb.fs` documentation [here](https://ipynb.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and answers on [ipynb import another ipynb file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186344/ipynb-import-another-ipynb-file) and [import a function from another .ipynb file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44116194/import-a-function-from-another-ipynb-file/49860804) all specify that documents must be in the same directory.

This is normally what I would do to import a function from an external ipynb file in the same directory,
`from ipynb.fs.full.my_functions import split_into_sentences`

I've moved `my_functions` into `functions/` and I've tried this,
`from ipynb.fs.full."functions/my_functions" import split_into_sentences`

and
`from ipynb.fs.full.functions/my_functions import split_into_sentences`

Neither works.

Is there any workaround to this?