# Create a Package using only Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, package

Creating a Python package consists of creating an init module and then having perhaps some other modules in the same level as init or higher to call the package. For example, the following is the structure for package A.

```
A/
     __init__.py
     A_1.py
Call.py
```

However, I am wondering if the same thing can be done in Jupyter notebook instead of .py modules.

```
   A/
         __init__.ipynb
         A_1.ipynp
    Call.ipynb
```

The motivation behind this is that sometimes you only have access to Jupyter notebook like in SageMaker so wondering how this can be done.

Comment: is this relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44116194/import-a-function-from-another-ipynb-file ?

Comment: Thank you this is helpful, but I am wondering if people can comment on other techniques and best practices to do this.

Answer (score 0):

## [nbdev](https://nbdev.fast.ai)

- example: the [fastai/fastai](https://github.com/fastai/fastai) package is written entirely in jupyter notebooks! And it uses `nbdev`

> Write, test, document, and distribute software packages and technical articles — all in one place, your notebook.

End-To-End Walkthrough Tutorial:
https://nbdev.fast.ai/tutorials/tutorial.html