# Importing error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'item'

Tags: python, class

I wrote (in Jupyter) a mother class (named Item) in a file named item and saved it in this path:

```
'C:\\Users\\Sareh\\Desktop\\New folder\\gg\\item.ipynb'
```

Now I wanted to write a child class of Item, therefore importing the item.ipynb file inside the child class file. Both of the files are in the same path. The path for child class is:

```
'C:\\Users\\Sareh\\Desktop\\New folder\\gg\\phone.ipynb'
```

but I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'item'
```

I do not know where I am doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
from item import Item

class phone(amir):

    def __init__(self, name:str,  price:float,quantity:int,broken_phone=0):
        super().__init__(
            name,price,quantity
        )
        assert broken_phone>=0, f"broken_Phone {broken_phone} should be positive"


phone1=phone('jj',5,6,7)
```

Comment: Please add the full path of Item class file

Comment: @Tamir What do you mean by full path?

Comment: 'C:\\Users\\Sareh\\Desktop\\New folder\\gg\\item.py' for example. Where have saved your class in.

Comment: @Tamir  Dear Tamir, I should add the full path where?

Comment: To the question, edit it and add so it will be possible to help

Comment: @Tamir  I added the path. I would thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to import `Item` from an `ipynb` file (Jupyeter notebook file).

Importing should (and expected) to be done from Python modules, files ending with `.py`.

How ever you can use [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44116194/import-a-function-from-another-ipynb-file) which might help you even though I would recommend using a `.py` to store your classes.