# Can I use !cp twice to import files from B to C when B imports from A to B?

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, syntax-error

What I'm trying to do is import functions and variables from a .ipynb file called A into B.ipynb, then import functions and variables from B to C.ipynb. The files are in Google Colab.

The way I've done this is to download A as a .py file, and then use the below code in B to seemingly access A.py:

```
!cp /content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/buildmergegraph8.py /content
```

followed by:

```
from buildmergegraph8 import *
```

This runs fine, giving me access to functions in A when called in B. Next is the problem, when I try to import from B into C using the following lines in C.ipynb:

```
!cp /content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/training_and_test_merge_graphs_with_labels.py /content
from training_and_test_merge_graphs_with_labels import *
```

This returns the error below. For clarity, the syntax error up arrow is pointing to the ! in !cp:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3553, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-3-5391baf2e3b0>", line 1, in <cell line: 1>
    from training_and_test_merge_graphs_with_labels import *

  File "/content/training_and_test_merge_graphs_with_labels.py", line 25
    !cp /content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/buildmergegraph8.py /content
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
```

I notice in the last line of this error that the problem is really the call in the .py file `training_and_test_merge_graphs_with_labels.py`, which is a .py version of the `training_and_test_merge_graphs_with_labels.ipynb`. I think the problem is the training_and_test_merge_graphs_with_labels.py file is a download of a .ipynb file, and that .ipynb file had the first two lines of written code in my question above. Basically, you can't execute !cp in a .py file.

Am I correct in my last sentence? If so, how can I import functions and variables from A to B, and then from B to C, if they are all .ipynb?

I was expecting to be able to import functions and variables from A.ipynb to B.ipynb, and from B.ipynb to C.ipynb, but it's possible I've chosen a method that doesn't allow this or there is a better alternative that does allow this.

Any help would be great, especially a solution that avoids me needing to make .py files of my .ipynb files.

Edit: I have since found that the error is a Google Colab issue: GC doesn't have access to local files, or something like this. I think this question could be closed?

Comment: `!cp` is a Jupyter Notebook directive, it's not Python syntax. It shouldn't be in scripts.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into Python-syntax coherent imports next then. If I want to import functions from A to B to C, all being .ipynb, is there a succinct way to do this, possibly without creating python scripts?

Comment: I have tried 'import import-ipynb' in B.ipynb coupled with 'from A.ipynb import *' but I am told there is no module A. This is confusing because B and A are in the same directory, so it should have worked. Still searching for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment but I would have asked what do you mean by "download A as a .py file".

There are 2 possible solutions that I believe might be suitable.

**First solution** (simple and my preferred solution)

Save all the relevant variables and functions in some .py file (e.g. `foo.py`) and save that file in the same directory as `A.ipynb`, `B.ipynb`, and `C.ipynb`. Example directory structure:

```
dir/
    A.ipynb
    B.ipynb
    C.ipynb
    foo.py
```

Then within your notebooks you can just import the same functions using

```py
from foo import some_function
```

**Second solution**

Use the `ipynb` library to import the relevant functions and other code directly from the notebooks. Download it using

```py
pip install ipynb
```

Then, import the functions, classes, and import statements from `A.ipynb` into `B.ipynb` and `C.ipynb` using

```py
# for specific imports
import ipynb.fs
from .defs.A import some_function
```

Or

```py
# For making all functions, classes, and import statements available in the new notebooks
import ipynb.fs.defs.A
```

I will assume that `A.ipynb`, `B.ipynb`, and `C.ipynb` are in the same directory.

Here is some documentation for `ipynb`: [docs](https://github.com/ipython/ipynb)

Here is a similar problem: [import a function from another .ipynb file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44116194/import-a-function-from-another-ipynb-file)

Comment: Thanks Blockface, I've considered using Method 1 only I'd need to go back and edit my .py module as I go. Method 2 looked very good, but for some reason it says 'No module named ipynb.fs.defs.A'. I definitely have the .ipynb files in the same directory, so I'm unsure what the problem is.