# Importing Notebook 'ipynb: approach and options

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipynb

I take note of Q&A discussing how to import `.ipynb` from one `notebook` to another. I won't be listing them here.

I also know I can use the magic `%run` command to bring in variables/definitions/functions from another `.ipynb` to my notebook. Obviously, noting its pitfalls [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72539764/20107918) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43615015/20107918). Nonetheless, it remains [versatile, allowing importing specific modules/sections only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65501851/20107918).

I'm fully aware that I can 'save as' `.py` and import the exported `.py` into my `notebook`.

With the maintainer of `nbimporter`, as of [2019:06](https://github.com/grst/nbimporter), advising against the continued use except truly desired, that brings me to my question.

Concerning `ipynb` [(last 23 Oct 17)](https://pypi.org/project/ipynb/) and `import-ipynb` [(last updated 22 Apr 22)](https://pypi.org/project/import-ipynb/),

1. Which one is *recommended* in terms of developers' maintenance?
2. Which is *recommended* based on its functionality?
3. What should one consider or look out for in opting for one of the two?
4. Any other factor to give thought to?

With `jupyterlab` and many platforms embracing/enabling `notebook`, [importing function from one `ipynb` to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44116194/import-a-function-from-another-ipynb-file) will continue for a considerable period of time to come.