# Python - importing a class within the same folder

Tags: python

I use python 3.5 with Anaconda (python 3.6) and I have a problem with importing a class within the same folder, even though I did exactly as explained in other places.

In `04-Convolutional Neural Network` Folder I have 
`04-Convolutional Neural Network.ipynb` and `logger.ipynb` files.

I want to import Logger class in `logger.ipynb`to `04-Convolutional Neural Network.ipynb`

First, I created a blank `__init__.ipynb` file in the same folder, I used:

```
from .user import User
from .dir import Dir
```

But I get the following error

```
No module named '__main__.user'; '__main__' is not a package
```

Any idea why do I have this problem? maybe because of the ipynb file system?

Edit: The files are in Desktop/NN/.... if it's important

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ipynb import another ipynb file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186344/ipynb-import-another-ipynb-file)

Comment: Importing `ipynb` files isn't the same as importing regular `py` files. See the duplicate link above - also refer [to this page on jupyter.org](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jupyter/notebook/blob/master/docs/source/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.ipynb)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to refer to the file your running (namely **main**). I don't use relative import much. But if `user` and `dir` are in the same directory as the file your running you should try (i.e. they are in the root of your python module):

```
from user import User
from dir import Dir
```

You should probably also rename the dir module, as `dir` is a builtin function in python.

Comment: When I omit the "." I get "No module named 'user'"

Comment: And have you tried it by changing the .ipynb file to .py files. You would need a `user.py`, `dir.py` and `__init__.py`.