# ModuleNotFoundError error while importing file in python

Tags: python

I am getting "**ModuleNotFoundError**" when importing a python file.PFB the code:

**testImport.ipynb**

```
feet_in_miles=5280
meters_in_kilometer=1000
beatles=["John Lenon","PAul McCartney",""]
```

**Modules.ipynb:**

```
import testImport
print(testImport.beatles)
```

On running Modules.ipynb, I am getting the below error:

> ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in ()
>
> ----> 1 import testImport
>
> 2 print(testImport.beatles)
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'testImport'

Kindly let me know what's the issue.

Comment: Does testImport really need to be an `ipynb` file? Could it not just be a normal `py` file? Importing a notebook into another notebook looks a bit [complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186344/ipynb-import-another-ipynb-file).

Answer (score 0):

check in your directory that testImport.py is in the folder where you are running the code . New program should be in same directory