# Notebook import Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to import a class i created in one Jupyter notebook, to a different notebook and i get an error message saying the following:

```
from newclassattempt import MyClass
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-4337d8f762d7> in <module>
----> 1 from newclassattempt import MyClass

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'newclassattempt'
```

How can i get around this and import my class?

Comment: For importing classes save the file containing your class as a `.py` instead of `.ipypnb` and be sure that they are in the same folder.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! the file was imported but its saying that it cannot import my class

Answer (score 0):

Please note that for the import to work we need the module to be a Python File, meaning with the extension `.py`.

The Jupyter Notebooks are not your plain python files and are thus not imported by normal python machinery

You can actually import a Jupyter Notebook using Hooks. A lot of it is detailed in the [documentation](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.html). But I also found another method

In the `thisnotebook.ipynb` (the one you are working on), all you need to do is use these commands:

```py
import import_ipynb
import newclassattempt
```

For this to work ensure that you install:

`pip install import-ipynb`

You can also use your `from newclassattempt import MyClass`

(The above was taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47558146))

Comment: thank you, the file imported, but still saying unable to import my class - perhaps i made an error with my class formation. will look into that

Answer (score 0):

Update: I found a fully functional solution.

As mentioned in other comments, the class needs to be stored as a `.py` file in the same folder as the jupyter notebook. the following code then worked:

```
import newclassattempt
ob = newclassattempt.MyClass(1)
```

where newclassattempt is the name of the `.py` file, ob is the object created and MyClass is the class in the `.py` file. The reason my class couln't be imported is because I had not referenced the  original file name