# How can I import variables to other python file in Python 3.3+?

Tags: python

I have a workspace structure like this:

```
folder
      file1
      file2
```

I want to import the variables of file1 to file 2. I am using python 3.7.6 on Anaconda Environment.

When I write in file 2

```
import file1
```

I get

```
Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file1'
```

I have tried to save an empty file called `__init__.ipynb` in the directory but it does not work.

I have tried:

```
from file1 import #variables
```

but I get this. [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qND8m.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All you need to do is `from file1 import your_function_or_class`

Comment: Hello Nitin, thanks for your quick response. I've tried that but I get this error. Check the screenshot [https://i.stack.imgur.com/qND8m.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```py
from file1 import YourClass # or your functions, etc.
```

Comment: Hello Adam, thanks for your quick response. I've tried that but I get this error. Check the screenshot [https://i.stack.imgur.com/qND8m.png]

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47558146/8286364). If it works for you, I'll update my answer and flag your question as duplicate.