# Unable to import another python file in google collab

Tags: python, import

I mounted the drive in google collab as follows -

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive/')
```

And I changed the working directory to where my code is

```
import os
os.chdir('/content/gdrive/My Drive/Mutual-Channel-Loss-Collab')
print(os.getcwd())
print(os.listdir())

/content/gdrive/My Drive/Mutual-Channel-Loss-Collab
['CUB_200_2011', 'CUB-200-2011.ipynb', 'my_pooling.ipynb']
```

I am running `'CUB-200-2011.ipynb'` and importing `'my_pooling.ipynb'` eventhough both are in the same directory, I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_pooling'`

Comment: `my_pooling.ipynb` is not module but `notebook` file. Module means pure Python code in file with extension `.py`. And you can import only `my_pooling.py`

Comment: [ipynb import another ipynb file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186344/ipynb-import-another-ipynb-file) - it needs something more then only standard `import`