# import variables and functions from ipynb file to python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have two files the first one is an ipynb file :

**code_A.ipynb**

```
x = 10

def square(y):

  return y**2
```

and another python file :

**code_B.py**

```
py_file_location = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks"

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(py_file_location))

from resources.code_A import *

result = x + 2

print('final result ', square(result))
```

The two codes are stored in the same file.

How can I get variables values and functions from the ipynb file to the python file.

**Error**

```
NameError: name 'code_A' is not defined
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186344/ipynb-import-another-ipynb-file

Comment: jupyter notebooks are not meant to be used as python modules. You can export/save the notebook as a `.py` file instead.