# I need help setting up my relative imports in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have spent so many hours trying out different answers on stack overflow that i no longer know what exactly is the proper way to use relative imports. Keep in mind this import should work on localhost and on a server

My project structure
[image]

**init**.py
[image]

Attempts to import Authenticate class in main.py result into ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
[image]

Kindly give an explanation or links with working examples of importing in the same directory.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to import a **Jupyter Notebook**, not a `class`. This is why you get the `ImportError`.

Have a look at this: [ipynb import another ipynb file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186344/ipynb-import-another-ipynb-file)

If you do not want to import from a Jupyter Notebook but from a module in a specified **path** you can try this:

```
import importlib.util
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("module.name", "/path/to/file.py")
foo = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(foo)
foo.MyClass()
```

You can also use relative import:

```
from foo import bar
```

Another option is to add a path to `sys.path` (over using import) to simplify things when importing more than one module from a single package:

```
import sys
# my_package dir contains mod_one.py, mod_two.py and mod_three.py
sys.path.append('/foo/bar/my_package')

from mod_one import foo
from mod_two import bar
from mod_three import foobar
```