# ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from 'app' (app.ipynb) in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, jupyter-notebook, importerror

Here is the directory structure

```
▾ 1projet/
  ▾ apps/
      __init__.ipynb
      Statistics.ipynb
      SWEDEN.ipynb
      UAE.ipynb
app.ipynb
index.ipynb
```

The code I wrote in `index.ipynb` is

```
import import_ipynb
from app import app
from app import server
from apps import UAE,SWEDEN,Statistics
```

which gives me this error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from 'app' (app.ipynb)
```

the code I wrote in `app.ipynb` is :

```
import dash

app= dash.Dash(__name__, suppress_callback_exceptions=True,
                meta_tags=[{'name': 'viewport',
                            'content': 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'}]
                )
server = app.server
```

and the file `__init__.ipynb` is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to import other `.ipynb` files from a `.ipynb` file.
Please beware that this is not the same as importing a python module (`.py`).
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186344/ipynb-import-another-ipynb-file) there is already an answer which might be interesting for you, there is already mentioned that all the notebooks have to be in the same directory for succesful import.

In your case you would have to install [ipynb](https://ipynb.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), and then import `app` and `server` with following lines:

```
from ipynb.fs.full.app import app
from ipynb.fs.full.app import server
```

In order to succesfully import the modules `UAE`, `SWEDEN`, `Statistics` you either have to put the `.ipynb` files into the same directory as `index.ipynb`, or you have to put the code in those files into `.py` files to support absolute import. In that case you would have to add `__init__.py` files to each folder hierachy.

In summary you have two options for your folder structure, first option:

```
▾ 1projet/
  __init__.py
▾ apps/
      __init__.py
      Statistics.py
      SWEDEN.py
      UAE.py
app.ipynb
index.ipynb
```

with imports:

```
from ipynb.fs.full.app import app
from ipynb.fs.full.app import server
from 1projet.apps import UAE, SWEDEN, Statistics
```

Second option:

```
app.ipynb
index.ipynb
Statistics.ipynb
SWEDEN.ipynb
UAE.ipynb
```

with imports:

```
from ipynb.fs.full.app import app
from ipynb.fs.full.app import server
from ipynb.fs.full.Statistics import *
from ipynb.fs.full.SWEDEN import *
from ipynb.fs.full.UAE import *
```

Comment: The first importing error is fixed ! Thank you. Just to clarify for the first option do I have to change the extension to .py? And for the second option do I have to get rid of the folders and have all files in the same folder?

Comment: @wageeh i am not sure if you can simply change the extension from `.ipynb` to `.py`. I think it's maybe easier to simply create the .py file with the same name and copy all code from the corresponding .ipynb file into the .py file.

Comment: @wageeh for the second option, yes you should get rid of all folders and have all files in the same folder

Comment: I went for the second option and I got this error ````ImportError: cannot import name 'Statistics' from 'ipynb.fs.full.app' (unknown location)````

Comment: sorry there was a mistake in my answer. you have to import with `from ipynb.fs.full.Statistics import *`