# Where must I save a Python class so as to call it in another file?

Tags: python, class, init

**Novice question**: I have currently written a Python script and in the middle I define a class which I use. Nevertheless, I understand I can have the class saved separately so as to call it again and again in different scripts with no need to define it all the time.

The class reads:

```
class hello

    """
    blah
    
    """

    def __init__(self, blah)

return self
```

If I am in the directory `dir`, and I have saved a Jupyter notebook `my_notebook.ipynb` should the class be saved in the same directory as `my_class.py`? And how do I call it in the notebook afterwards?

Comment: Do research on how imports work: https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html For your situation, `from my_class import hello` should work. Also check https://stackoverflow.com/a/52923466/6402099

Answer (score 1):

Save the file in same directory and use `import` in your .py files. Like if you have class saved in a file called **classes.py** then you must write `import classes` in your other .py file. And they must be in the same directory.

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: If incase it don't work then feel free to ask me again and if it works then mark it as correct answer so others can see that it is working. ```Happy Coding```