# How to import function from one notebook file into another file on AWS Emr Notebook using pyspark

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

I have written a .py function on an emr notebook and want to use this function on another emr notebook file when I import the function with the file name it gives an error. Can someone please Help thanks [image: error when i tried to import the function]
[image: other file code]

Comment: notebooks are not python file, you cannont import them with an `import` command. 
But I think you have some magic commands like `%run welcome.ipynb` which could do the trick

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ipynb import another ipynb file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186344/ipynb-import-another-ipynb-file)

Comment: hi i have use the run magic command and it didn't worked

Comment: Hi Can you share an example in which i can import files from one notebook to another on EMR CLUSTER

Comment: `it didn't worked` does not mean anything. What did you try ? what was the output ? any error message ?

Comment: hi @Steven sorry for the late reply I got stuck in some other work, I have tried to run this Magic run command and it says module not found, currently, i am running to notebooks and I want to import the function of Notebook a to Notebook B Errors are attached below  

https://imgur.com/Sl3Tg9X

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238899/discussion-between-steven-and-kaolin).