# Auto-reloading an ipynb file from another ipynb file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, interactive, autoreload

I learned from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47558146/3552975) on how to import another ipynb in an ipynb file :

```
import import_ipynb
from another_ipynb import function
```

But if the function has been changed, it will not be autoreloaded, and I tried many methods:

```
# 1. autoreload magic function

%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload
# or %autoreload 2

# 2. %aimport magic function

%aimport another_ipynb

# 3. importlib 

import importlib
importlib.reload(another_ipynb)
```

All don't work, and then could anyone please provide any suggestions or point me in the right direction? Is it possible or allowed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same problem here. Surprised that no-one posted about this.