# How to import a variable from .ipynb to .py file?

Tags: python, jupyter

I have two files named as **funcs_.py** and **data.ipynb** and I am trying to import a variable conn from ipynb to py file
I am doing like this

```
from ipynb.fs.full.data import conn
```

But it is giving me error that cannot import conn from data

Any help is  appreciated

Answer (score 0):

See axil's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47558146/2985694) in [Importing an ipynb file from another ipynb file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186344/importing-an-ipynb-file-from-another-ipynb-file) (even though the question is about importing .ipynb into .ipynb it works for importing .ipynb into .py).

Note that what you will `pip install` has a **hyphen** (`import-ipynb`), what you import has an **underscore** (`import_ipynb`)

---

*Aside: I found your question by searching [import ipynb function regular python] in a search engine. I clicked the other results even though they didn't match what I was looking for but I tried it and it worked.*