# Run command in another notebook or file - jupyter lab

Tags: python

I'm using jupyter lab and I have a very huge list (len > 10000). In order to organize things better, I'd like to create another file containing only this list and call it to another notebook -  The purpose: just don't want to have a huge list in this notebook where I'm analyzing things.

For example:

**In one file (it may be .py or any other supported by jupyter lab):**
`my_list = [1,2,3......, 10000]`

**In another jupyter notebook (where I want to analyze things):**
I want to call this list and, let's say, calculate it's len -
`my_list_len = len(my_list)`

How can I do that?

I thought about creating a .py, however I don't know how to call it to another notebook to get my list

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43615015/15521392 does that help ?

Comment: If it's just a list of numbers have you considered saving it as a .csv file? https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: It's a list... I have considered .cvs, but I was thinking it may have an easier way