# can't import local file from same folder - Reportmissingimport

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

i'm working on visual studio code and can't import files from the project's folder
[that's the folder of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADwPS.png)

a code

```
import frame
```

is underlined on the word "frame" and produces following output:

```
Import "frame" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports
```

i tried many things and solutions given on similar problems on SO, i checked global variable ComSpec, it's value is proper - C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe, i installed , i set `"python.analysis.extraPaths"` to  `["frame", "charts", "app"]` and gave value to `python.defaultInterpreterPath` (its previous value was just 'python'). what is interesting - i ahd no `settings.json` value before, i created it myself by opening settings.json in visual studio code (i can't edit settings.json when opened by using ctr+shift+p), copying contents and pasting it in file `settings.json` which i created in `.vscode` folder - it was not created by visual studio code although i'm using virtual environment

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit:

Docs on [Importing Jupyter Notebooks as Modules](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/4.x/examples/Notebook/rstversions/Importing%20Notebooks.html#importing-jupyter-notebooks-as-modules)

##### Solution 1

I also found this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47558146/17597213), using `import-ipynb`, that I'll paste below:

> Install my helper library from the command prompt:
>
> ```py
> pip install import-ipynb
> ```
>
> Import it from your notebook:
>
> ```py
> import import_ipynb
> ```
>
> Now `import` your `.ipynb` notebook as if it was a `.py` file
>
> ```py
> import TheOtherNotebook
> ```
>
> This python-ipynb module is just one file and it strictly adheres to the official howto on the jupyter site.
>
> PS It also supports things like `from A import foo`, `from A import *` etc
>
> PPS Works with subdirectories: `import A.B`

##### Solution 2

On the same question as linked above, there is this [additional answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52923466/17597213) that could be helpful as well, I'll paste it below:

> Run
>
> ```
> !pip install ipynb
> ```
>
> and then import the other notebook as
>
> ```py
> from ipynb.fs.full.<notebook_name> import *
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```py
> from ipynb.fs.full.<notebook_name> import <function_name>
> ```
>
> Make sure that all the notebooks are in the same directory.
>
> Edit 1: You can see the official documentation here - https://ipynb.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
>
> Also, if you would like to import only class & function definitions from a notebook (and not the top level statements), you can use ipynb.fs.defs instead of ipynb.fs.full. Full uppercase variable assignment will get evaluated as well.

---

Try turning the directory into a package by adding a `__init__.py` file. Here's an example of how it would work:

**Directory Structure:**

```
ProjectRoot:.
│   frame.py
│   other.py
│   __init__.py
```

**`frame.py`:**

```py
MSG = "Hello World"
```

**`other.py`:**

```py
import frame
print(frame.MSG)
```

**`__init__.py`:**

```py
# Empty file
```

If you were to run `other.py`, you'd get:

```
Hello World
```

Heres a link to documentation on python's [import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-import-system)

Comment: well, i work in jupter notebooks, so shouldn't it be __init__.ipynb?

Comment: i tried using both shortcuts - __init__.py and __init__.ipynb and neither work

Comment: I didn't realize my original solution wouldn't work in jupyter notebooks,  so I added (and linked) some alternative solutions I found.

Comment: what if these solutions still doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Simple and straightforward way is to convert your `frame.ipynb` file to `.py` file.

[image]

[image]

Also about the configuration of `"python.analysis.extraPaths"`. The scripts are all in the same folder, and `"python.analysis.extraPaths"` does not need to be configured at this time.

[image]

If subfolders exist, the configuration is as follows:

```json
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "./pyfile"
    ]
```

*It is the path, not the file name*

[image]

is the path, not the file name

Comment: well, i will need to import 3 files, which i wanted to write in notebook and making copy of each to store it as python file isn't optimal but hey, it works. Thanks

Comment: Glad my answer was helpful to you. If you don't mind, you can change the status of the answer, which can help those with similar problems to solve the problem faster.

Comment: it actually didn't work, i came across another problem but after it i just lost hope and decided to not part the project for 3 files xD